# JPA 3 table join mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 tables, a, b and c, with a join table a_b_c, which has the 3 FKs, an auto-gen PK and no other columns. For entities, I would like to have:

```
class A{
 Map<B, Set<C>> _;
}

class B{
 Map<A, Set<C>> _;
}

class C{
 Map<A, Set<B>> _;
}
```

How do I achieve this with JPA annotations? Is there a better way to structure the entities than above?

This works, but I'm not sure how to get a Map> instead of the Map.

```
class A {
   @JoinTable(name = "a_b_c",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id"))
   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "b_id")
   @ElementCollection
   Map<B, C> _;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?